# slow speed of specific set of frames from video in android project

Tags: android, android-videoview, video-processing, audio-processing, slowmotion

I need to implement an app, where video is being showing on video view. User select specific range of frames from video and that frames speed slow down. Basically i am done with showing frames of video and user can also select set of frames. Next don't know how to slow audio and video speed of selected set of frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Vitamio Api](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) video slowing(playing video with change playback speed) can be performed. For test purpose user can use vitamio sample available on GitHub [Vitamio android sample](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/master/vitamio-sample). Or can add class MediaPlayerDemo_Video avaialbe in vitamio sample to slow video.

Here is a code for MediaPlayerDemo_Video

```
    public class MediaPlayerDemo_Video extends Activity implements OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private String path;
    private Bundle extras;
    private static final String MEDIA = "media";
    private static final int LOCAL_AUDIO = 1;
    private static final int STREAM_AUDIO = 2;
    private static final int RESOURCES_AUDIO = 3;
    private static final int LOCAL_VIDEO = 4;
    private static final int STREAM_VIDEO = 5;
    private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;

    /**
     * 
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
            return;
        setContentView(R.layout.mediaplayer_2);
        mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888); 
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    }

    private void playVideo(Integer Media) {
        doCleanUp();
        try {

            switch (Media) {
            case LOCAL_VIDEO:
                /*
                 * TODO: Set the path variable to a local media file path.
                 */
                path = "";
                if (path == "") {
                    // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
                    Toast.makeText(MediaPlayerDemo_Video.this, "Please edit MediaPlayerDemo_Video Activity, " + "and set the path variable to your media file path." + " Your media file must be stored on sdcard.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case STREAM_VIDEO:
                /*
                 * TODO: Set path variable to progressive streamable mp4 or
                 * 3gpp format URL. Http protocol should be used.
                 * Mediaplayer can only play "progressive streamable
                 * contents" which basically means: 1. the movie atom has to
                 * precede all the media data atoms. 2. The clip has to be
                 * reasonably interleaved.
                 * 
                 */
                path = "";
                if (path == "") {
                    // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
                    Toast.makeText(MediaPlayerDemo_Video.this, "Please edit MediaPlayerDemo_Video Activity," + " and set the path variable to your media file URL.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                break;

            }

            // Create a new media player and set the listeners
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
        // Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    }

    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
            return;
        }
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
        playVideo(extras.getInt(MEDIA));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void doCleanUp() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    }

    private void startVideoPlayback() {
        Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
        holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

layout code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >
        </SurfaceView>
    </io.vov.vitamio.widget.CenterLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```